# Нормальный алгоритм Маркова

Tags: алгоритм, нормальный-алгоритм-маркова

Алфавит `a`, `b`. Если слово является палиндромом - написать `a`. Если нет - стереть все. Может кто помочь???

Comment: Вам в каком виде алгоритм нужен? Программа на языке программирвания или еще как-то? Или непонятно, как алгоритм работает?

Comment: как последовательность действий

Comment: что-то типа этого: 0b→.11b→.22b→.33b→.44b→.55b→.66b→.77b→.88b→.99b→b0b→.....

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин, а откуда цифры взялись? Их же не было в алфавите.

Answer (score 3):

1. Заменяем одну из букв на `y`
2. Двигаем `y` к началу строки
3. Превращаем `y` в `x`
4. `x` и следующую за ним букву двигаем к концу строки
5. По символам, окружающим `x` определяем может ли эта трока быть палиндромом:

   - они одинаковые - да - уничтожаем все три, продолжаем с шага 1
   - они разные - нет - заменяем всё на `z`
   - есть только символ справа - у нас палиндром нечётной длины - уничтожаем оба
6. Двигаем `z` к началу строки, стирая предшествующий ему символ
7. Заменяем единственный `z` на пустую строку и **заканчиваем**
8. Если получилась пустая строка, заменяем на `a` и **заканчиваем**

Теперь расставляем эти правила в таком порядке, чтобы можно было после каждого шага начинать с начала списка:

```
1
2 1
2 3 1
2 3 4 1
2 3 4 5 1
2 3 4 5 6 1
2 3 4 5 6 1 7
2 3 4 5 6 1 7 8
```

Получается так:

```js
var rules = `
ay → ya
by → yb

y → x

xaa → axa
xab → bxa
xba → axb
xbb → bxb

axa → 
bxb → 
axb → z
bxa → z
xa → 
xb → 

az → z
bz → z

a → ya
b → yb

z →• 
 →• a
`.split`
`.filter(Boolean)
.map(s => s.match(/(\S*) *→(•?) *(\S*)/).slice(1));

function solve(s) {
  RUN: while (1) {
    for (var [l,f,r] of rules) {
      if (s !== (s=s.replace(l,r))) {
        if (f) return s
        continue RUN
      }
    }

    return s
  }
}

console.log(
  ["abba","","a","b","baab","ababa","babab","aaa","bbb","aaaabaaa","bbbabbbb"]
  .map(solve) == "a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,,"
)

document.addEventListener('input',
  ({target:{value:v}}) => console.log(`"${v}": ${solve(v)}`)
)
```

```html
<input>
```

Answer (score 1):

допустим есть массив слов `['0b','11b','22b','33b','44b','55b','66b','77b','88b','99b','b0b']`. 
Алгоритм будет следующий:

```js
var arr = ['0b','11b','22b','33b','44b','55b','66b','77b','88b','99b','b0b'];



function isPolindrom(item) {
  var reverse =  item.split("").reverse().join("");
  return reverse == item;
}

function checkArr() {
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if(isPolindrom(arr[i])) {
       console.log('a');
       return true;
     }
   }
   arr = [];  //если нет полиндрома удаляем массив
}

checkArr();
```

Comment: это не то, что нужно

Comment: Данный ответ никак не связан с [нормальными алгоритмами Маркова](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC), а следовательно не может являться ответом на вопрос. Чтобы решение просто так не пропадало, предлагаю задать вопрос с самоответом, как это было сделано [тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/605283/revisions), а этот ответ удалить. Перенести ответ к другому вопросу я не могу. Блокировку поставил, чтобы было нельзя голосовать за ответ.