# Определить палиндром

Tags: javascript

Есть некий массив слов `['0b','11b','22b','33b','44b','55b','66b','77b','88b','99b','b0b']`

Необходимо определить есть ли в массиве слово - палиндромом.

---

*Вопрос добавлен по [совету](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735776/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/735798#735798)  Qwertiy*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111507/how-to-write-palindrome-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 5):

```js
let arr = ['0b','11b','22b','33b','44b','55b','66b','77b','88b','99b','bob'];
   
let isPolindrom = (string) => string.split('').reverse().join('') == string; //проверка на полиндорм
   
let checkArray = arr => arr.some(str => isPolindrom(str));

console.log(checkArray(arr));
```

Comment: Можно чуть упростить: `let checkArray = arr => arr.some(str => isPolindrom(str));`

Comment: @Yaant Большое спасибо, за такую хорошую правку в код, с радостью внесу ее в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Из Вики:

> Палиндро́м (пе́ревертень) — число, буквосочетание, слово или
>   текст, одинаково читающееся в обоих направлениях.

В данном контексте функция может выглядеть так:

```js
var arr = ['0b','11b','22b','33b','44b','55b','66b','77b','88b','99b','b0b'];



function isPolindrom(item) {
  var reverse =  item.split("").reverse().join("");
  return reverse == item;
}

function checkArr() {
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if(isPolindrom(arr[i])) {
          return true;
     }
   }
  return false;  
}

checkArr();
```