# Как реализовать нормальные алгоритмы Маркова

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, интерпретатор, нормальный-алгоритм-маркова

Как работают [нормальные алгоритмы Маркова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC) и как реализовать для них интерпретатор?

Answer (score 2):

Описание напишу завтра.

```js
class Rule {
  constructor(rule) {
    var match = rule.match(/^\s*(\S*)\s*→(•?)\s*(\S*)\s*$/)
    
    if (!match) throw new Error(`Invalid rule string '${rule}'`)
    
    this.left = match[1]
    this.final = !!match[2]
    this.right = match[3]
  }
  
  toString() {
    return `${this.left} →${this.final?'.':''} ${this.right}`
  }
}

class Markov {
  constructor(rules) {
    this.rules = rules
    this.value = ""
  }
  
  step(value) {
    for (var rule of this.rules) {
      var res = value.replace(rule.left, rule.right)
      
      if (res !== value) {
        return { value: res, rule: rule, done: rule.final }
      }
    }
    
    return { value, rule: null, done: true }
  }
  
  *steps(value) {
    do {
      var {value, rule, done} = this.step(value)
      yield { value, rule }
    } while (!done)
  }
  
  run(value) {
    for (var {value} of this.steps(value)) {}
    return value
  }
}

var txtInput = document.getElementById('input')
var elOutput = document.getElementById('output')
var taRules = document.getElementById('rules')

function getRules() {
  return taRules.value.split('\n').filter(Boolean).map(r => new Rule(r))
}

document.getElementById('run').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  elOutput.textContent = ""
  
  try {
    var engine = new Markov(getRules())
    elOutput.textContent = engine.run(e.target.value)
  } catch (e) {
    elOutput.textContent = e.message
  }
})

document.getElementById('steps').addEventListener('click', async function (e) {
  var value = txtInput.value
  elOutput.textContent = value + '\n\n'
  
  try {
    var engine = new Markov(getRules())
    
    for (var {value, rule} of engine.steps(value)) {
      elOutput.textContent += `${rule}\n${value}\n\n`
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100))
    }
    
    elOutput.textContent += "=== DONE ==="
  } catch (e) {
    elOutput.textContent = e.message
  }
})
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 8px; }
textarea { float: left; height: 100%; margin-right: 8px; resize: horizontal; }
section { height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
label, input { display: block; width: 100%; }
label { cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 8px; }
div { flex: 0 0 auto; }
pre { margin: 8px 0 0; flex: 1 1 auto; overflow: auto; }
```

```html
<textarea id=rules>ay → ya
by → yb

y → x

xaa → axa
xab → bxa
xba → axb
xbb → bxb

axa → 
bxb → 
axb → z
bxa → z
xa → 
xb → 

az → z
bz → z

a → ya
b → yb

z →• 
 →• a</textarea>
<section>
  <div>
    <label>Input:<input id=input value=ababa></label>
    <button id=run>Run</button> <button id=steps>Steps</button>
  </div>
  <pre><output id=output></output></pre>
</section>
```

PS: Подробнее о программе из примера (а также более компактный вариант кода): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736405/178988

Comment: *"Описание напишу завтра"* - всё ещё ждём ...

Comment: @Kromster Ибо сказано: "Одно то не должно быть сокрыто от вас, возлюбленные, что у Модератора один день, как тысяча лет, и тысяча лет, как один день" :)

Comment: @Yaant, я забыл. Но галочки тоже не стоит ;)